# ExtJs:Initialize variable from Store

Tags: extjs4

Hi i am using ExtHs 4.

I have a global variable which needs to be initialized from the store.

```
var cp=0;

Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.define('Init', {
            singleton: true,
            cp: 0
        });

Ext.define('loggedUserList', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields: ['id','name']
            });

            loggedUser = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: 'loggedUserList',
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url : url+'/lochweb/loch/users/getLoggedUser',
                    reader: {
                     type: 'json',
                        root: 'provider'
                    }                   
                },
                listeners: {
                    load:function(loggedUser){
                        Init.cp = loggedUser.getAt(0).data.id;

                    }
                }

            }); 
});
```

i am using the value of cp in another url as follows,

```
Ext.define('vocbList', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields: [
                    { name: 'id', mapping: 'id' },
                    { name: 'code', mapping: 'code' },
                    { name: 'loinc', mapping: 'loinc.loincNumber' }
                ]
            });     

            var vocabulary = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {             
                model: 'vocbList',
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',                   
                    url : url+'/lochweb/loch/vocabulary/getVocabularyByProvider?providerId='+Init.cp,                   
                    reader:  {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'Vocabulary'
                    }
                }
            });
```

but its value is still 0.How to assign its value form store so that it can be reused for other purpose.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by another url? Outside of Ext scope or inside it?

Comment: Need to use the value of cp in url inside  another Store,like url : url+'/lochweb/loch/vocabulary/getVocabularyByProvider?providerId='+cp,

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a callback.

Store call is being done asynchronously so that the browser will not freeze while the store get the data from the database.

```
me.vocabulary.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        //here the store has been loaded so records are not empty
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Ext.onReady`, define a global class like this:

```
Ext.define('Init', {
    singleton: true,

    cp: 0
});
```

Then you can get or set **cp** anywhere you want:

```
Init.cp = 'some';
var myCp = Init.cp;
```

Comment: In "another url" (your second codes) you still use '+cp' instead of '+Init.cp' -- Check this out.

Comment: Hi Natasha,yes i have tried as  url : url+'/lochweb/loch/vocabulary/getVocabularyByProvider?providerId='+Init.cp but still value of cp is 0.Any help